# Laravel3: Variables that has to be set forever

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ $description }}" />
```

It is a variable stored in a `custom.config.php`. That file can be anywhere. (I'm new to Laravel)

How can I ensure Laravel runs it each time? I'm not going to use `->with('description', $description');` every time I call a view.

Looking for something like: `{{ Config::get('website_description') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that variable to the before route filter:

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    //Do stuff before every request to your application...
    $website_description = Config::get('website_description');  
    View::share('website_description', $website_description);
});
```

You can then directly access that variable in your view.

Comment: What if I call a different before function, like isAdmin(). Will it still run because we extend "before"?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but that function is global and it will be executed every time. You could call isAdmin() inside the anonymous function...

Comment: View::share() doesn't even need to be in a filter.

Comment: I think this needs to go a little deeper than that guys - there's an infrastructure thing here... For example, I am wondering if any layouts have been considered.  A view composer might be useful with that, or just accessing Config::get() itself wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: @jesal I mean we can add different before checks, like hasAdminsRights so user cannot enter admin restricted areas. I believe there wouldn't be any conflict issues since we extend "before" method directly? Also, this solution sounds a little weird. I just hack the before function and have to filter all my routes. I don't want to use routes. I just want to access those values directly from views. It shouldn't be route.php's duty.

Comment: I think the only other way I could think of achieving this would be to create a base controller where you can add something like this in it's constructor: $view->website_description = Config::get('website_description');

Comment: @jesal Forked. Will have a look when I get time. Handling ajax requests also answered a question I was about to ask. :)